# Creating multiple lines on a Google Chart by looping through getJson urls

Tags: json, loops, google-visualization

I have a getJson function with a parameter called "feed" which loops through multiple URLs.
I want to create a Google Chart with multiple lines similar to the screenshot with each line coming from a different JSON feed.
However when I try, it seems to just produce one line (I think because it's looping through but just picking up the final url in the loop). [This is what I want to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXwvu.png)

This is the code I've added:

```
    function chartLoop(feed){
var chartDivs = "chart_div1";
$.getJSON(feed + '&start_date=' + dateFrom + '&end_date=' + dateTo + '&' + order  , function(json){

var dataSet = json.dataset;
var dataAll = json.dataset.data;
var title = dataSet.name;
var database = dataSet.database_code;
var count = dataAll.length;

  // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

  // Set a callback   to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
  // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
  // draws it.
  function drawChart() {

    // Create the data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();



    data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Amount');


  for(var i = 1; i < count ; i++) { 




   data.addRows([
     [dataAll[i][0], dataAll[i][1]]
   ]);     

   }
    // Set chart options
    var options = {'title':title,
                   'width':1000,
                   'height':700};

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById(chartDivs));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  } 



})};
```

Answer (score 0):

wrapping in a closure / `function`, instead of a `for` loop, should lock the value of `i`...

```
$.each(new Array(count), function (i) {
   data.addRows([
     [dataAll[i][0], dataAll[i][1]]
   ]);     
});
```

Comment: sorry I never got back to you on this. I couldn't get it to work in the end but thank you